# Can't overwrite file in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, payara

I'm using docker compose to set up a payara server and need to overwrite the domain.xml file. I'm currently doing it through

`volumes:
   - './domain.xml:/opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml'`

but when i compose it with `docker-compose up` it keeps saying that it could not rename domain.xml to domain.xml.bak. Is there any way i can get permissions to overwrite it or make sure the rename works ?

Comment: Why do you need to override something that you are explicitly mounting?

Comment: I don't want to mount it, i want to copy it. But i can't seem to find a way to copy it

Comment: Would it be better to mount a config folder for it, so it will overwrite the domain.xml file ?

Comment: Yes, that's a nice solution. Many projects do it this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
command: sh -c 'cp /tmp/domain.xml /opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml && YOUR_PREVIOUS_COMMAND'
volumes:
   - ./domain.xml:/tmp/domain.xml
```

Or edit your current `command` (or `CMD`) if it's a script, prepending the copy.

---

**Edit:** This alternative is very handy and elegant.

```
command: sh /run-from-compose.sh
volumes:
   - ./domain.xml:/tmp/domain.xml
   - ./run-from-compose.sh:/run-from-compose.sh
```

run-from-compose.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /tmp/domain.xml /opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml

YOUR_PREVIOUS_COMMAND
```

You don't need to modify the image, just mount a custom script that acts as `command`.